# Typescript - Kotlin-like copy function

Tags: typescript

In Kotlin a `data class` can be copied using its auto-generated `copy` function.

```
val jack = User(name = "Jack", age = 1)
val olderJack = jack.copy(age = 2)
```

The copy function signature, as per documentation ([Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)):

```
fun copy(name: String = this.name, age: Int = this.age) = User(name, age)
```

Can something like this be done in TypeScript?
Is this an acceptable solution, or can it be improved somehow?

```
export class User {
    constructor(
            public name: string,
            public age: number) {}

    copy(parameters: {
        name?: string,
        age?: number
    }): User {
        const { name, age } = parameters
        return new User(name || this.name, age || this.age)
    }
}
```

This could be solved even with a `Partial<User>`:

```
copy(partialUser: Partial<User>): User {
   return new User(
            partialUser.name || this.name,
            partialUser.age || this.age)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deconstruct the item as shown below:

```
class User {
    constructor(
            public name: string,
            public age: number) {}
}

const jack = new User("Jack", 1);

const newJack = { ...jack, age: 2 };
```

This results in the copy, except the age, which is now `2`.

The ordering is important (i.e. age must follow the object deconstruction).

Extended example below:

```
class User {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public age: number) { }

    copy(user: Pick<User, 'name' | 'age'>) {
        return new User(user.name, user.age);
    }
}

const jack = new User("Jack", 1);

const newJack = jack.copy({ ...jack, age: 2 });

console.log(newJack);
```

Comment: Wouldn't I lose eventual instance / static functions?

Comment: I have added a wider example where `newJack` is the full `User`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you find `Pick` more appropriate then `Partial`?

Comment: With `Pick` you say "it must have the members I state", wheras `Partial` says "I don't know what it's going to have". In our case, we can be quite strict that we expect name and age to be supplied and we don't care about `copy`. So the following will be caught as an error in our `Pick` example: `const newJack = jack.copy({ age: 2 });`

Comment: Interesting! I could even just use `(user: Pick<User>): User { ... }` then.
Do you think that my `Partial` example was not appropriate? I ask so I'm able to understand if I'm doing right or wrong in general terms

Comment: Oh wait, as my constructor arguments are all required I'm forced to list all its properties in `Pick<T, K>`

Comment: You could elevate it to an interface and avoid the management overhead.